# PhpUnit Testing stub method multiple return

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am doing some PHPUnit testing with symfony2. I am having a problem with one particular test.

I am testing a response form one of my Class of course one response is true one false. I have a Mock of my Database and I have a stub for one of the methods from my databaseRepository.

The issue is that in one test I do a stub to a method with an valid array, second test i just want to query to be invalid null.

my db MOck:

```
    //Setting up mock of database repository class
    $this->db = $this->getMockBuilder('DatabaseRepository')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->db->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRecord')
        ->will($this->returnValue(self::$registrationRecord));

    $this->db->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRecord')
        ->willReturn(null);
```

So I am trying to have two different expects but this obviousley does not work.....is it possible to have a stub method to have two different returns..?

test1:

```
    <?php


class UnsubscribeRegistrationTemplateTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @var UnsubscribeRegistrationTemplate
     */
    protected $object;

    /**
     * @var ValidationClass
     */
    public $validate;

    /**
     * @var DatabaseRepository
     */
    public $db;

    //Database Record Mock
    public static $registrationRecord = array
    (
        'rowid' => '96',
        'unsubscription' => 'N',
        'updated' => 'BB'
    );

    /**
     *
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        //Setting up mock of validation class
        $this->validate = $this->getMockBuilder('ValidationClass')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->validate->expects($this->any())
            ->method('validateInput')
            ->willReturn(true);

        //Setting up mock of database repository class
        $this->db = $this->getMockBuilder('DatabaseRepository')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->db->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getRegistrationRecord')
            ->will($this->returnValue(self::$registrationRecord));

        $this->db->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getRegistrationRecord')
            ->will($this->returnValue(null));

        $this->db->expects($this->any())
            ->method('setPreRegistrationEnquiryUnsubscriptionEnabled')
            ->willReturn(true);

        $this->object = $this->createUnsubscribeRegistrationTemplateInstance();
    }

    /**
     * @return UnsubscribeRegistrationTemplate
     *
     */
    public function createUnsubscribeRegistrationTemplateInstance()
    {
        //initialize Unsubscribe Registration Template
        return new UnsubscribeRegistrationTemplate
        (
            $this->validate,
            $this->db
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param array $mapping
     * @return Request
     */
    public function createRequest(array $mapping)
    {
        $request = new Request();

        foreach ( $mapping as $k =>$v)
        {
            $request->query->set($k, $v);
        }

        return $request;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function testUnsubscribeRegistrationTemplateValidResponse()
    {
        $request = $this->createRequest(array(
            'registration_id' => '96',
            'source_channel' => 'BB'
        ));

        $response = new Response(
            true,
            'Unsubscription successful'
        );

        $this->assertEquals($response, $this->object->create($request));
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function testUnsubscribeRegistrationTemplateEmptyResponse()
    {
        $request = $this->createRequest(array(
            'registration_id' => '96',
            'source_channel' => 'BB'
        ));

        $response = new Response(
            false,
            'Registration Record Not Found.'
        );

        $this->assertEquals($response, $this->object->create($request));
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function testIsAlreadyRegisteredValidResponse()
    {
        //Testing record is already unsubscribed
        $registrationRecord = array(
            'unsubscription_enabled' => 'Y'
        );

        $this->assertTrue($this->object->isAlreadyUnsubscribed($registrationRecord));
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function testIsAlreadyRegisteredInValidResponse()
    {
        //Testing record not unsubscribed
        $registrationRecord = array(
            'unsubscription_enabled' => 'N'
        );
        $this->assertFalse($this->object->isAlreadyUnsubscribed($registrationRecord));
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        unset($this->object);
    }

}
```

Comment: move the expect in the relative test method, as example, if `testIsAlreadyRegisteredInValidResponse`  want that `getRecord` return null, move the code there and remove the other expect from setup.

Comment: yes I was doing this before but the expect function was getting highlighted  by my PhpStorm and i though it will not work so never even boathered to try :/ now i did and it works perfect but php storm hihglights it  saying: Method expect not found in class databaseRepository

Comment: Don't worry about it, is only because phpstorm don't undestand the correct object type probably due a wrong or missing PHPDoc annotation. So you solved?

Comment: yes i did thx up voted it but in all fairness @Pierre Marichez mentioned this form the start

Comment: of course, Pierre immediately understand what problem do you have. The important is that you fixed the problem and... you learn how better use the testing framework!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in many ways.
Here are two ways that may suits your needs.

## 1 - Move the getRecord() expects to the tests

```
/**
* @test
*/
public function ifTrue()
{
    $this->db->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getRecord')
    ->will($this->returnValue(self::$registrationRecord));

    $request = $this->createRequest(array(
        'id' => '10',
        'code' => 'BB'
    ));

    $response = new Response(
        true,
        'successful'
    );

    $this->assertEquals($response, $this->object->create($request));
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function ifFalse()
{
    $this->db->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getRecord')
    ->willReturn(null);

    $request = $this->createRequest(array(
        'id' => '10',
        'code' => 'BB'
    ));

    $response = new Response(
        false,
        'Record Not Found.'
    );

    $this->assertEquals($response, $this->object->create($request));
}
```

As you can see, there's a lot of duplication, so let's use [dataprovider](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers).

## 2 - Using @dataProvider

```
protected function getDataForTest()
{
    return array(
        array(self::$registrationRecord, true, 'successful'),
        array(null, false, 'Record Not Found.')
    );
}

/**
* @dataProvider getDataForTest
* @test
*/
public function ifTrue($getRecordValue, $bool, $message)
{
    $this->db->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getRecord')
    ->will($this->returnValue($getRecordValue);

    $request = $this->createRequest(array(
        'id' => '10',
        'code' => 'BB'
    ));

    $response = new Response(
        $bool,
        $message
    );

    $this->assertEquals($response, $this->object->create($request));
}
```

Using @dataProvider you can use as many values as you want to test all cases.

Comment: Hey thx for your answer `i have tried the first way but it then says: expect not found in class

Comment: Where and when do you instanciate your dbMock?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use the PHPUnit `at()` method to check method invocation at certain index. So you must substitute the  `expects` value argument with the correct index's call.

So you can use the following code:

```
//Setting up mock of database repository class
$this->db = $this->getMockBuilder('DatabaseRepository')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$this->db->expects($this->at(0)) // Mock the  first call
    ->method('getRecord')
    ->will($this->returnValue(self::$registrationRecord));

$this->db->expects($this->at(1)) // Mock the  second call
    ->method('getRecord')
    ->willReturn(null);
```

http://www.andrejfarkas.com/2012/07/phpunit-at-method-to-check-method-invocation-at-certain-index/

Hope this help

Comment: Hey thx for your replay. I actualy tried this solution propably should of mentioned but it did nto work i had this message: d> when invoked at sequence index 0.
The expected invocation at index 0 was never reached.

Comment: The assertion said  that in your test the method was never executed

Comment: @Koper can you post the entire test class?

Comment: my test method or the method i am trying to stub

Comment: @Koper, in order to replicate your problem, post all the code you can post that can be useful for local execute your scenario

Comment: @Koper you must edit your question not my answer! :)

Comment: Be careful when using at(), as it's represent each time a method is called on the mock (not just the method you add an expects() on).